# Spliting and Writing a Text file Lines into dataframe columns

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a text file which is written in Notepad++, which contains a series of numbers at each line. like:

12451

I want to read this text file into python and assign each digit to a specific column of a dataframe, in a same order for all lines (here with 5 columns, as the length of each line).
how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using [pd.read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf) function. e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_fwf("file.txt",widths=[1,1,1,1,1],header=None)
```